# rename html tag class by c#

Tags: html, class, tags, rename

I want to replace class name of a tag when a method execute by c# in code behind. Is there any solution? what is suitable code?

for instance:  convert to

only in code behind not by jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a serverside (`runat="server"`) control and change its CssClass attribute.

[MSDN reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.cssclass.aspx).